# Is there a Stack Exchange community for the Microsoft Windows PowerShell?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My interests are related to the following items:

- The Microsoft Windows command-line pre-processing system batch files, which are related to the `C:\Windows\System32\Cmd.Exe` executable binary file;
- The Microsoft Windows PowerShell integrated shell scripting environment, which is related inclusively to the `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.Exe` executable binary file;
- The *Bourne Again Shell* scripting environment, which is largely known in some areas as Bash.

I would like to ask a question related to PowerShell somewhere. At first sight, it does not seem that there is a specific community related to PowerShell. Is there anything similar somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Super User](https://superuser.com) has a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) [tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powershell)

> Windows PowerShell is a command line shell and scripting language for Windows that supersedes the CMD.exe shell and batch language. PowerShell is also an automation engine for Windows that provides functionality similar to Windows Script Host and VBScript.

That has more than 4000 questions. Have a look at some of those and see if yours would fit there.

Alternatively if you're writing a PowerShell program and have got stuck on some bit of syntax then [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) also has a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) and a [powershell-core](/questions/tagged/powershell-core) [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-core)

> PowerShell is a cross-platform command line and scripting utility from Microsoft. Use this tag for questions about writing and executing PowerShell scripts ONLY. Programming questions specific to the cross-platform version PowerShell Core (Windows, macOS, and Linux) should be tagged [powershell-core].

Comment: Using the tag markup here is not really helpfull, as that makes it link to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powershell which will lead to nothing ofcourse.

Comment: It formats the tag as a tag and I provide the real link on the word tag.

Answer (score 1):

There is no dedicated site for the subject of PowerShell.

That doesn't make it that there is no place for them in the Network. For example Stack Overflow has the [[PowerShell]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) tag, with close to 90K questions. Its description immediately offers advice on which questions are to be asked where:

> PowerShell is a cross-platform command line and scripting utility from Microsoft. Use this tag for questions about writing and executing PowerShell scripts ONLY. Programming questions specific to the cross-platform version PowerShell Core (Windows, macOS, and Linux) should be tagged [[powershell-core]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-core). Questions about system administration should be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Simultaneously there is also a [[bash]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) tag on Stack Overflow.